# Font Embedding german characters( "ü") problems

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript, flex3, flex4

i am facing one font problem, my website is to operate in five languages, one of them is german, so few characters like ü etc.are not getting displayed properly.

so for example, in english, i have one word "unhappy", in german it has to be displayed as "unglücklich",

actually i m still using Flex3.0, so[image] when i receive this value from PHP end, i m getting it as mentioned in this image.., so "unhappy" text when it is getting displayed finally is worthless., can n e one plzz help me out, my website is almost finsihed, just few of these small problems is creating problem, Thank you very much in advance

Thank you

Ankur Sharma

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a character encoding problem, not a font embedding problem.

Make sure your PHP script delivers text encoded in Unicode (UTF-8) format.

Comment: thanx Claus, it might be what u r saying, coz the same answer i m getting from other member, so i m goin to do, wht u guys r  saying,

Comment: do u have any working demo, can u plzz send me , if thats possible, thanx

Comment: i have no demo for you, but this is a good summary: http://abeautifulsite.net/blog/2010/07/tips-for-supporting-utf-8-in-your-php5-applications/

Answer (score 2):

That is an UTF-8 text being displayed as ANSI text - not a *font* problem, but a *character encoding* problem. PHP has to encode this text properly before sending it to Flash, or encode it after receiving it (depending on what exactly you're doing). See [utf8_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php) and [utf8_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-decode.php).

Be aware, it may even be the case that you're encoding it twice.

Comment: all ryt, at my end on the flex side, whatever i m receving is getting displayed properly, the php person has to send me the correct characters, thanx , i'll check out this with php person, thank u veru much, if you have n e working php code for this, can u send me that, i'll give that to my php developer.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem to this with CKeditor. It encodes the German characters in the source, although on the display it looks fine. If I change the source then it saves OK, but whenever I switch back to the display behind the scenes it alters the characters again. I've been looking for a setting to change in the CK config but haven't found one that works yet.

Flex will display German characters but in my case, and Ankur's it seems, only if it is given them in the first place.

Comment: Thanx Daniel for your response, but this problem is solved now, actually this is the work that was to be done from the php side, as i am a flex developer, so we get data from our php developers, so whatever i was getting on my tool, that was problematic, so as they corrected it from their side, so my flex projects displays the content properly, thanx n e ways, hav a gr8 time

Comment: That was what I found. It needed the config in CKEditor to be set correctly. Once the webservice stopped passing in encoded German characters, Flex worked nice. It can only display what you give it.